# Get Twitter messages via url parameter

Tags: twitter

I try to get N numbers of the last twits and I use this url

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=cnn&count=20
```

I guess that parameter `count` will give me exact number of the last twits but it shows some arbitrary numbers of tweets.

Any clue which parameter I have to use to get accurate number of twits?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the inconsistent count might be that you aren't receiving retweets. I think Twitters algorithm grabs count tweets and pulls the retweets out. Maybe try adding the parameter "include_rts=true".